# Can we run a substrate full node(where all pallets are implemented) instead of starting with substrate-node-template?

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

Can we run a substrate full node(where all pallets are implemented) instead of starting with substrate-node-template ?

Comment: of course. if you are going to build a parachain, pls start with this, https://substrate.dev/cumulus-workshop/

Comment: @ClarkLee no not a para chain a standalone chain... The reason y i have asked this question is after cloning substrate-node-template i am getting lot of errors while implementing pallets. So , I thought that if I clone full node I will get all the pallets implemented.

Comment: ok. if parachain, started from cumulus. if standalone, start from what Swader said. careful about which version you are building, I recommend the latest tag, monthly-2021-08. From my experience, most errors came from the wrong version or the unmatched rust version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just compile and run substrate, not substrate-node-template: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate - this has basically all the pallets built in.

Comment: i have cloned that and got an error while running cargo build --release command.
 error[E0557]: feature has been removed <br/>

   --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/environmental-1.1.2/src/lib.rs:42:43
     |
  42 | #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), feature(const_fn))]
     |                                           ^^^^^^^^ feature has been removed
     |
     = note: split into finer-grained feature gates

Comment: Please make an issue on the repo

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after `node` rather than `node-template`:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node